# Locking button clicke event, using lock in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

Using Lock in asp.net how can i prevent more than one user to click on button. I mean only one user has to click on button at a time, more than one user not to click on button.
How can i use lock, any refrence to study.

Comment: try this link [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114262/6-ways-of-doing-locking-in-NET-Pessimistic-and-opt](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114262/6-ways-of-doing-locking-in-NET-Pessimistic-and-opt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot really prevent different users from clicking "*the same*" button on "*the same*" page. But you can prevent several requests from being active in the same code block at the same time:

```
private static object PadLock = new object();
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lock (PadLock)
    {
        // do work here. only one thread can run code in this block at any one time
        // start by verifying if the work was already done. if not do the work
    }
}
```

Although this would serialize access to the code in `Button1_Click`, I would advise against using ti if it's not absolutely necessary. The `lock` statement blocks (potentially forever) until the previous lock holder releases the lock.